# Primefaces Progress Bar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having a problem with my Prime Faces progress bar. I have it setup so that it polls every second to retrieve a value for "progress". This value is then used to fill the progressBar.

My progressBar:

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="checkoutProgress" value="#{conversionsCreateNewConversion.retrieveProgress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated"/>
                        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{conversionsCreateNewConversion.retrieveProgress}" update="contentRegion:j_idt99"/>
```

My method to update progress:

```
public void retrieveProgress()
{
    progress=0;
    if(allFiles==null)
    {
        progress = 0;
    }
    else if(allFiles!=null && fileNames==null)
    {
        progress=10;
    }
    else if(allFiles!=null && fileNames!=null && fileCid==null)
    {
        progress=20;
    }
    else if(allFiles!=null && fileNames!=null && fileCid!=null && fileUrl==null)
    {
        progress=30;
    }
}
```

The values within the method are filled in other methods and are Lists.

Can anyone see my problem? I am new to polling and cant seem to get it to work with progressBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method return nothing (void). So the value can be only empty.

You should create getter / setter for progress and put them in the value in progressbar.